# Modal Segue To Navigation Controller With Transparent View Turns Grey

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a view that I would like to be transparent.  I have set the background to default, but every time I do the segue the view is first transparent the way I want it to be but then it turns grey. Can anyone tell me what my issue is?

Comment: Have you added the backgroundColor in your viewDidLoad or?

Comment: @RashwanL I have some code that creates a blur effect, but it works for all my other views so Im not sure why it doesn't work for this particular one

Comment: Try to add all if this in your segue destination viewControllers viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad will fire when the view is about to load.

Comment: @RashwanL I also have some text views that aren't appearing in their proper text color or font size when I run the project.  My Xcode might be screwed lol

Comment: For the textViews check that you have used autoLayout so that they are within your frame.

Comment: @RashwanL Thanks, the text view thing worked, but I am still having trouble with the blur effect for the background.  I have the code running in the viewDidLoad() but it still doesn't work.  I am using the same method that allows it to work for my other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `firstViewController` do the segue as usual

`firstViewController`:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: nil)
```

Then in your `secondViewController` add the backgroundColor

`secondViewController`:

```
fun viewDidLoad(){
    // Set your backgroundColor and add blur effect
    self.view.backgroundColor = ....
}
```

Comment: I tried setting the background color to clear but it still turns black a few seconds after the view appears.

Comment: Add this code the last thing you do in viewWillAppear instead, I think you probably changing the backgroundColor somewhere after viewDidLoad...

Comment: Wtf I didnt change anything and ran it and I had no problems, then I ran it again and I got the problem again.

Comment: Ok so if I go into a view that has the transparent background with the blur and then go back to the view with the issue it works, but if I go straight into the view it doesnt work

Comment: When you had the code in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in viewWillAppear and make sure that you hit it when you navigate to the viewController every time.

Comment: It does but then it disregards the code and turns black

Comment: WHOOPS I had it on Current Context instead of Over Current Context. My bad